# Service unavailable in REST API call from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, apache, rest

From a basic installation of wordpress + woocommerce I created a custom plugin that calls an API in GET protocol with bearer token. I copied the php curl code from postman and both locally and on postman I can connect to the rest service without problems. But if I use the same code from wordpress, I get "503 Service Unavailable". Not being an expert I don't know if the problem is due to an incorrect configuration of apache2 / .htacces file or if wordpress adds headers or other things that make the call fail in 503

I report here the call curl

```
protected function getGetData($url,$token){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $auth= 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            $auth
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

I have already tried turning off all wordpress plugins with no results. the particular thing is that by changing some settings sometimes the call returns 200 the first time but from the second onwards it continues to return 503. From postman and local php instead it works every time the function is executed

Answer (score 0):

I did some checks and in these cases I noticed that it is advisable to first disable each plugin on the wordpress side and then, check that there are no controls by whoever supplies the API. In my case I found that the server had a call limit that I had exceeded and for which it was returning 503.